# Show single dot in numeric input

Tags: html, input

Im working with MVC C# in the view side, I have a numeric input in some cases the value must be decimal, between 0 and 1, .5 for example.
In order to make the input easier to the user I want to add the dot so the user only type "5" instead of ".5".

However the dot is not showing in the input, if I inspect the element the input has the value=".", and when the submit is made I get 5 not .5.

```
if (item.Inspection.MinValue >= 0 && item.Inspection.MaxValue < 1)
{
    <input type="number" step="any" name="Inspection@(item.InspectionID)" value="." class="form-control" style="font-size:30px" required autocomplete="off" />
}
else
{
    <input type="number" step="any" name="Inspection@(item.InspectionID)" value="" class="form-control" style="font-size:30px" required autocomplete="off" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` on an `<input type="number">` must be... well... a number. And `.` is not a number. If you want to make sure the user chooses a value between 0 and 1, you can use the the `min` and `max` attributes:

```html
<input type="number" min="10" max="100" step="any" name="Inspection@(item.InspectionID)" class="form-control" style="font-size:30px" required autocomplete="off" />
```

You can also use an `<input type="text">` and recreate some of the numeric functionality using JS, but that's not a good idea.

Comment: It's not about validation, I just want to add a dot as same as you do it with the keyboard

Comment: You simply can't do that with an `<input type="number">`. What if the input control is not a textbox and the user is not typing the number? The user might be using speech recognition to input the number. In that case, a value of `.` would make no sense.